# I'm trying to make a little age game but it closes

Tags: python

I'm an absolute beginner at python and I am trying to make a little game where you can see in what year you'll be a certain age. The first section that calculates when you will be 100 years old works but when I come to the second part and I answer with yes it asks the questions until I fill in the current age, after that it just closes down.

This is my code:

```
import datetime
import time
name = input("What is your name: ") # name input
age = int(input("How old are you: ")) # age input
year1 = str((datetime.datetime.now().year - age)+100) # calculates in what year age will be 100
print(name + " will be 100 years old in the year " + year1)

answer = input("Do you want to know another age: ")
if answer == "yes": 
    age1 = int(input("What age do you want to know: ")) # asks for different age than 100 if answer was yes
    age = int(input("How old are you: ")) # age input
    year2 = str((datetime.datetime.now().year - age)+age1) # calculates in what year input age will be
    print(name + " will be", age1, "years old in the year " + year2)
if answer == "no":
    print("Have a nice day!")
    time.sleep(5) 
    exit()
```

Can anyone tell me why it does this and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when your script reaches its end, other than it to "close down"?

Comment: If you want to keep on asking the same set of question then use loops

Comment: If I answer "yes" I'm asked two numbers and then I get the expected output. I didn't understand what you described as the problem.

Comment: How are you running the program? I suspect it is working as expected, it's just that whatever is running it closes immediately. Try running it in idle or terminal.

Comment: you probably want to unindent the last two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `while True` and `break` when answer is `no`, like this:

```
import datetime
import time
name = input("What is your name: ") # name input
age = int(input("How old are you: ")) # age input
year1 = str((datetime.datetime.now().year - age)+100) # calculates in what year age will be 100
print(name + " will be 100 years old in the year " + year1)

while True:
    answer = input("Do you want to know another age: ")
    if answer == "yes": 
        age1 = int(input("What age do you want to know: ")) # asks for different age than 100 if answer was yes
        age = int(input("How old are you: ")) # age input
        year2 = str((datetime.datetime.now().year - age)+age1) # calculates in what year input age will be
        print(name + " will be", age1, "years old in the year " + year2)
    if answer == "no":
        print("Have a nice day!")
        break
```

output:

```
What is your name: sample
How old are you: 24
sample will be 100 years old in the year 2097
Do you want to know another age: yes
What age do you want to know: 200
How old are you: 24
sample will be 200 years old in the year 2197
Do you want to know another age: yes
What age do you want to know: 300
How old are you: 24
sample will be 300 years old in the year 2297
Do you want to know another age: no
Have a nice day!
```